# How is it guaranteed that electrical connections could be made without destroying a diode laser?

Tags: laser, semiconductor-physics

A diode laser is a tiny diode and requires a microscope to see it.  Since a laser generates a good amount of heat, the diode should be destroyed with the produced heat. But it does not happen. but why and how?

More specifically, my question is: how is it guaranteed that one can make electrical connections using standard lab equipment without destroying the laser?

Comment: How does one work with electronic components that are sensitive to static electricity? By avoiding static electricity. There is plenty of equipment for that... carpets/floor mats, antistatic tables and table mats, properly grounded soldering equipment, wrist bands, ion generators... there is an entire industry that makes these products for you, and then all you have to do is to be careful.

Comment: If you are asking about the process of bonding the wires to the diode chip then your success is _not_ guaranteed.  It's standard practice across the whole electronics industry to test every component.  Some failures are expected, the cost of that is built-in to the budget, and the dead parts are thrown away.  But you asked about _standard lab equipment_.  Unless the purpose of your lab is to investigate techniques for bonding wires to chips, then you probably are working with _packaged_ devices that already have been tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High power diode lasers are often mounted on thermo-electric coolers.  They remove excess heat, while stabilizing temperature, which is important for stable operation.

Comment: Well, maybe not the really high power ones. TECs are pretty inefficient, needing about 100W to pump 10W, so dumping 110W into the heat sink. The diodes on TECs tend to be the precise ones for wavelength multiplexing in fibers and the like in my experience.